# I can't get 2 javascripts to work simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a website im building on a Joomla CMS i call inside the head tag these javascripts :

```
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.history.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.galleriffic.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.opacityrollover.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<style>.noscript { display: none; }</style>');</script>
```

I have two javascripts inserted on my index.php

One for a slideshow (gallerific) and another one for a dropdown menu.
The slideshow javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // We only want these styles applied when javascript is enabled
    $('div.content').css('display', 'block');

    // Initially set opacity on thumbs and add
    // additional styling for hover effect on thumbs
    var onMouseOutOpacity = 0.9;
    $('#thumbs ul.thumbs li, div.navigation a.pageLink').opacityrollover({
        mouseOutOpacity:   onMouseOutOpacity,
        mouseOverOpacity:  1.0,
        fadeSpeed:         'fast',
        exemptionSelector: '.selected'
    });

    // Initialize Advanced Galleriffic Gallery
    var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
        delay:                     2500,
        numThumbs:                 10,
        preloadAhead:              10,
        enableTopPager:            false,
        enableBottomPager:         false,
        imageContainerSel:         '#slideshow',
        controlsContainerSel:      '#controls',
        captionContainerSel:       '#caption',
        loadingContainerSel:       '#loading',
        renderSSControls:          true,
        renderNavControls:         true,
        playLinkText:              'Play Slideshow',
        pauseLinkText:             'Pause Slideshow',
        prevLinkText:              '&lsaquo; Previous Photo',
        nextLinkText:              'Next Photo &rsaquo;',
        nextPageLinkText:          'Next &rsaquo;',
        prevPageLinkText:          '&lsaquo; Prev',
        enableHistory:             true,
        autoStart:                 true,
        syncTransitions:           true,
        defaultTransitionDuration: 900,
        onSlideChange:             function(prevIndex, nextIndex) {
      // 'this' refers to the gallery, which is an extension of $('#thumbs')
      this.find('ul.thumbs').children()
        .eq(prevIndex).fadeTo('fast', onMouseOutOpacity).end()
        .eq(nextIndex).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);

      // Update the photo index display
      this.$captionContainer.find('div.photo-index')
        .html('Photo '+ (nextIndex+1) +' of '+ this.data.length);
        },
        onPageTransitionOut:       function(callback) {
      this.fadeTo('fast', 0.0, callback);
        },
        onPageTransitionIn:        function() {
      var prevPageLink = this.find('a.prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      var nextPageLink = this.find('a.next').css('visibility', 'hidden');

      // Show appropriate next / prev page links
      if (this.displayedPage > 0)
        prevPageLink.css('visibility', 'visible');

      var lastPage = this.getNumPages() - 1;
      if (this.displayedPage < lastPage)
        nextPageLink.css('visibility', 'visible');

      this.fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
        }
    });

    /**************** Event handlers for custom next / prev page links **********************/

    gallery.find('a.prev').click(function(e) {
        gallery.previousPage();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    gallery.find('a.next').click(function(e) {
        gallery.nextPage();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    /****************************************************************************************/

    /**** Functions to support integration of galleriffic with the jquery.history plugin ****/

    // PageLoad function
    // This function is called when:
    // 1. after calling $.historyInit();
    // 2. after calling $.historyLoad();
    // 3. after pushing "Go Back" button of a browser
    function pageload(hash) {
        // alert("pageload: " + hash);
        // hash doesn't contain the first # character.
        if(hash) {
      $.galleriffic.gotoImage(hash);
        } else {
      gallery.gotoIndex(0);
        }
    }

    // Initialize history plugin.
    // The callback is called at once by present location.hash. 
    $.historyInit(pageload, "advanced.html");

    // set onlick event for buttons using the jQuery 1.3 live method
    $("a[rel='history']").live('click', function(e) {
        if (e.button != 0) return true;

        var hash = this.href;
        hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');

        // moves to a new page. 
        // pageload is called at once. 
        // hash don't contain "#", "?"
        $.historyLoad(hash);

        return false;
    });

    /****************************************************************************************/
    });
  </script>
```

And the dropdown menu:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  

var axm = {


    openMenu:  function() {
      $('#newmenuheader').stop().animate({ 'height':'140px'}, "fast");
        },

    closeMenu:  function() {
      $('#newmenuheader').stop().css({'overflow': 'hidden'}).animate({'height':'55px'}, "fast");
        },

};

</script>
```

I can get only one script run at a time not both. If one runs the other doesn't. I need to have them both.
At the time the javascript for the slideshow is running. Is there a conflict of some sort ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? Are you using Prototype or any JS libraries other than jQuery? Try using `jQuery` in place of `$` in the dropdown menu code.

Comment: As a side note, why are you using javascript to write a style tag? It's not like the code is based on some condition or anything either. Just write the style tags directly in there..

Answer (score 1):

The second chunk of javascript code with the `var axm` needs to be added to the

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {}
```

Otherwise the browser doesn't know to run it. And you should re-write this function, don't use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {}
```

just use

```
$(function(){
    //your javascript and jQuery here for binding events, styles, and functions
}
```

this is a function that will run once the page is ready.

Comment: +1 Though you're right with seeing a problem, _"Otherwise the browser doesn't know to run it."_ isn't the reason.

Comment: in that second chunk of code he is binding some events, so if you don't instantiate them some time after the page loads then they won't run.  "browser won't know to run it"  is probably too loosely used jargon here, thanks.

Comment: If the selector runs before the elements are rendered the selector won't grab the elements thus the events won't attach. (in my non native English language...)

Comment: I did this (merging the two scrips in one) and now none work !.                      
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {

   
   
   var axm = {
 
     
 openMenu:  function() {
      $('#newmenuheader').stop().animate({ 'height':'140px'}, "fast");
     },
     
 closeMenu:  function() {
      $('#newmenuheader').stop().css({'overflow': 'hidden'}).animate({'height':'55px'}, "fast");
     },
 
}
   
   
    // We only want these styles applied when javascript is enabled
    $('div.content').css('display', 'block');
=======================-CODE OMITTED==========
   });
  </script>

Comment: @SamOne you can edit our post to include your updated script.  Also see what gdoron said above, if the elements haven't been rendered yet then the jQuery selectors cannot attach to anything.